# cohomology with compact support

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Where is the cohomology with compact support useful? It seems that, a part from proving Poincaré duality, we also use it to compute the top dimensional cohomology group of closed manifolds: isn't singular cohomology sufficient here?

Thanks

Comment: Sufficient for what?

Comment: In any case it is easy to underestimate the importance and usefulness of having a cohomology theory with a nice duality property such as Poincaré duality.

Comment: @Mariano I meant sufficient to compute top dimensional cohomology group or module of a closed manifold

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a closed manifold, cohomology and cohomology with compact supports coincide, but for open manifolds they do not.  The top dimensional cohomology with compact support is always one-dimensional for a connected orientable manifold, regardless of whether or not the manifold is closed.  Furthermore, on any (connected orientable) manifold, closed or not, Poincare duality is true when expressed as a duality between cohomology and cohomology with compact support in the complementary dimension.  Thus cohomology with compact support is a natural tool when working with non-closed manifolds.