# Poincare duality on non closed manifolds

Tags: homology-cohomology, hodge-theory

For proving the *Poincare duality* $H_{\mathrm{dR},p}\cong H_\mathrm{dR}^{m-p}$ one can use the bilinear form $B:H_\mathrm{dR}^p\times H_\mathrm{dR}^{m-p}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $B([\omega],[\beta]):=\int_M\omega\wedge\beta$. $B$ only depends on the cohomolgy class $[\omega]$ since if $\omega_1,\omega_2\in[\omega]$ one has for a closed $(m-p)$-form $\beta$
$$\int_M\omega_1\wedge\beta=\int_M\omega_2\wedge\beta-\int_M\mathrm{d}\left(\alpha\wedge\beta\right)=\int_M\omega_2\wedge\beta$$
if $M$ is closed and orientable.

However, some authors (e.g. Jost) only assume $M$ to be compact and orientable and still use the equation above in their proofs. I am aware that there is [chomolgy with compact support](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39214/cohomology-with-compact-support/39221#39221), but as far as I can see the equation only holds if $\partial M=\varnothing$, i.e. $M$ is closed. What am I missing?

Comment: If one of the forms (and one of the cohomologies) is with compact support then the equation holds. Poincare duality works for oriented open manifolds, as a duality between ordinary and compactly supported cohomologies.

Comment: @user8268 On a compact oriented manifold $M$ with boundary and a compactly supported $(m-1)$-form $\eta$ why does $\int_M\mathrm{d}\eta=\int_{\partial M}\eta=0$ hold? Or is there another argument for the equation?

Comment: for a compact manifold with boundary one needs to take forms with support in the interior of $M$ (or at least with vanishing restriction to the boundary). The resulting cohomology is the cohomology relative to the boundary of $M$.

Comment: @user8268 Strangely, that has not been mentioned either explicitly in one of my reference sources.